# Android Application not Seeing All Classes in Library

Tags: android, eclipse, shared-libraries

All,

I am creating a Android app on Eclipse.  I have an external library that has methods that I would like to call.  I have created the appropriate "libs" directory, copied my jar file to it and added that library through Properties > Java Build Path > Add Jars...

The odd thing is that I can reference a class in that jar file just fine but that class can't reference other classes in that same jar.  I have several other applications that use the same jar file and they all work fine.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

try to add it as an external library...

Comment: Tried that (removed reference in build path configuration and added it back as external jar pointing to file in project directory).  Same issue.  One of the errors I'm getting is: "05-24 20:09:26.128: W/dalvikvm(534): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/tempuri/EHDLookupService; (442)" is that helps.